# Scope, closures and bindings in javascript. Why is my loop not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, variables, dictionary, scope, closures

I am trying to create a list so that when the LI element is clicked, a specific div is displayed.
I want to read the id of the div and other properties from a dictionary.
So, the dictionary looks like this:

```
var ifSrc = {"welcome":"welcome.html",
          "proceduresAndComputers":"../proceduresAndComputers/index.html",
          "someId":"../someSourceFileForAnIFrame"}
```

and the function to form those LI elements

```
function createMenu(){
    var listy = document.getElementById("sidebar");
    for(var key in ifSrc){
        var elem = document.createElement('li');
        elem.innerHTML = key;
        elem.className = "unselected";
        elem.addEventListener("click",function(){openDiv(this,key);},false);
        listy.appendChild(elem);
    }
    listy.firstElementChild.className="selected";
}
```

So, the Menu (UL with LI elements) looks ok, but no matter which LI I click on, the openDiv function passes the right value for `this`, but same value for `key`. In particular, it passes the last value for `key` in the `ifSrc` dictionary. However, the innerHTML of each elem (which is set to `key`) appears fine. I checked the documentation for addEventListener and I couldn't find much.

Why is this happening? Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure that you're capturing the correct key value (with a closure, in my example below). The way you have it now, `key` is always a reference to the same value in all of the click events. You can copy the *current* value of `key` for each click event by doing this:

```
    elem.addEventListener("click", (function(k) {
        return function() { 
            openDiv(this, k);
        }
    })(key), false);
```

[**Demo - jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/dL4fs/2/)

For reference -- check out "The Infamous Loop Problem" as [explained here](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/).

Comment: So javascript won't evaluate key when I loop through the keys of the dictionary, but at runtime, when the eventListener is called? Is that why I want to add a closure? If that is the case, why didn't I get all the LI items saying the same thing? Any good pointers where I can read about this?

Comment: The problem was with your inner function. Each function you were assigning as a click event had a reference to the same `key` variable. By using a closure you capture the *current* value of `key` and pass *that* into your click handler. See my edit, by the way, I changed it a bit to make it more obvious what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, that link to the infamous loop helped, as well as the section "closure in loops: a common mistake" here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: You're welcome. There's also [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) that has a ton of discussion   and examples on the matter.